# how to set up shadow in a button active css

Tags: css, button, frontend, web-frontend

[image]

The first photo is when the button is inactive. The second photo is when the button clicked. This code isn't mine. I have read the code but I still don't get where does the border shadow come from. The buttons have a class called "random-btn". And this is the only css code about random-btn:

```
.random-btn {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  background: var(--clr-primary-10);
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  transition: var(--transition);
  border-color: var(--clr-primary-5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.random-btn:hover {
  background: var(--clr-primary-5);
  color: var(--clr-primary-1);
}
```

Also this is the following variables mentioned above:

```
--clr-primary-10: hsl(205, 100%, 96%);
--clr-primary-5: hsl(205, 78%, 60%);
--clr-primary-1: hsl(205, 86%, 17%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the default properties the browser is giving the button. It is the `border-style` property.

If you use Chrome Developer Tools, the default styling is in italic and there you can see *`border-style`*.

```css
.btn {
  border-style: outset;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Here is an example ahowing all `border-style`s.

```css
.btn {
  animation: borders 10s infinite;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.btn::after {
  animation: bordersNames 10s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
  content: "";
}

@keyframes borders {
  0% {
    border-style: dotted;
  }
  10% {
    border-style: dashed;
  }
  20% {
    border-style: solid;
  }
  30% {
    border-style: double;
  }
  40% {
    border-style: groove;
  }
  50% {
    border-style: ridge;
  }
  60% {
    border-style: inset;
  }
  70% {
    border-style: outset;
  }
  80% {
    border-style: initial;
  }
  90% {
    border-style: none;
  }
  100% {
    border-style: dotted;
  }
}

@keyframes bordersNames {
  0% {
    content: "dotted";
  }
  10% {
    content: "dashed";
  }
  20% {
    content: "solid";
  }
  30% {
    content: "double";
  }
  40% {
    content: "groove";
  }
  50% {
    content: "ridge";
  }
  60% {
    content: "inset";
  }
  70% {
    content: "outset";
  }
  80% {
    content: "initial";
  }
  90% {
    content: "none";
  }
  100% {
    content: "dotted";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">My border is</button>
```